# Shared node.js global vars with elastic beanstalk autoscaling

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

I have a node.js app running in elastic beanstalk with auto scaling configured. Let's say I have the following code:

```
var app = express();

var getCounter = 0;

app.get('*', function(req, res){
  getCounter = getCounter + 1;
  res.send("That was get request " + getCounter);
});
```

Since I want `getCounter` to be the same across all my instances, what options do I have for storing it besides in my database? It feels too "transient" for storing in the db. Would this be a candidate for putting into a cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a persistent database. Everything else is futile. If you don't persist this somewhere that's accessible by all processes it's local data and it will quickly fall out of sync. Global variables are per-process, not system-wide.

You can use anything you want, like [Redis](http://redis.io/), a distributed cache like [Memcache](https://memcached.org) or a more full-featured database from Amazon RDS if you prefer. There's no easy way to share data without some kind of centralization.